# Copy a DriveItem but overwrite

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I want to copy and overwrite the existing file but cannot do it without getting the error nameAlreadyExists .

As a workaround I seem to have to download it into a stream and then reupload it.

The code is as per the API

```
await graphClient.Sites.Root.Drives[documentLibraryId].Items[fileId]
            .Copy(newFileName, parentReference)
            .Request()
            .PostAsync();
```

As a workaround I may have to download the file into a strea and then upload it like as per the following which seems to work

```
await RetryWithExponentialBackoff.RunAsync(async () =>
        {
            uploadSession = await graphClient.Drives[driveId]
           .Root
           .ItemWithPath(filePath)
           .CreateUploadSession()
           .Request()
           .PostAsync();
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually you just need to set the microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior to replace. This works fine with functions such as [moving](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-move?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). However, the Api ignores the specified conflict behavior with the copy function. More information on the bug here: [link to github issue](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/981). It does not seem to be a priority for Microsoft, since the bug was reported over a year ago and nothing happened since. So you will most likely need a workaround.
Another idea for a workaround:

1. Copy the DriveItem to the target document library or folder, but use for example a combination of the current date and the drive item id instead of the desired file name newFileName to make sure, that you not get a conflict with any existing file.
2. Change the copied DriveItem's name to the desired file name newFileName, e. g.:

   PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/siteId/drives/driveId/items/itemId

   {
     "name": "newFileName",
     "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior":"replace"
   }

   In my tests, this replaced the existing file with the name newFileName with the copied file.

With this workaround, you do not need to download and reupload the file. Thus, the performance should be better. However, the user may wonder about weird file names.